# Hosting Multiple Websites on Webmin

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-virtualhost, webmin

I set up a couple of Virtual Servers (websites).

The problem is, does not matter what URL I use, I will always be redirected to the first one Virtual server I created.

Here is the redirective text for the second website that is not working: 
It is the same as the first one except for the paths...

```
DocumentRoot /home/maoz/www
ServerName michelleandomer.com
<Directory /home/maoz/www>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerPath /home/maoz/www
```

Can you guys refer me to a manual that explain what do to in order to solve this issue?